# How to yield a decimal result from two integer inputs?

Tags: floating-point, integer

I have written the following code in my C++ program, but near the end, I need to compute the value of `x1 / SumOfIntegers`. I am a total beginner, and I would really appreciate anyone who could help me figure out how to yield a decimal result as an answer. I have been using 2 as all of my integer inputs, so `x1 = 2` and `SumOfIntegers = 10`. Therefore `x1 / SumOfIntegers` should equal `.2`, but I keep getting `1` as the output. Can someone please help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graphics.h"
#define     _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double x1;
    double x2;
    double x3;
    double x4;
    double x5;
    double SumOfIntegers;
    const double Radius = 250;
    double CircumferenceOfCircle;
    double x1PercentOfTotal;

    cout <<
        "You will be prompted to enter five integers for a pie chart \n";

    cout << "Enter integer 1: ";
    cin >> x1;

    cout << "Enter integer 2: ";
    cin >> x2;

    cout << "Enter integer 3: ";
    cin >> x3;

    cout << "Enter integer 4: ";
    cin >> x4;

    cout << "Enter integer 5: ";
    cin >> x5;

    cout << "Sum of integers: " << x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 << endl;
    cin >> SumOfIntegers;

    cout << "Circumference of Circle: " << 2 * (M_PI) * Radius << endl;
    cin >> CircumferenceOfCircle;

    cout << "x1 Percentage of Total " << (double)(x1) /
        (double)(SumOfIntegers) << endl;
    cin >> x1PercentOfTotal;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to calculate the `SumOfIntegers` value:

```
cout << "Sum of integers: " << x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 << endl;
cin >> SumOfIntegers;
```

You've asked the *user* to type in the sum and the user is often *very* bad at data entry. I suggest you *store* the value yourself. (I also suggest *not* waiting for user input before continuing. That's annoying.)

Try this:

```
SumOfIntegers = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5;
cout << "Sum of integers: " << SumOfIntegers << endl;
```

(Note especially that I've removed the `cin >> SumOfIntegers` line.

To see specifically what I'm talking about, change just that one value between runs:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 8" | ./foo 
You will be prompted to enter five integers for a pie chart 
Enter integer 1: Enter integer 2: Enter integer 3: Enter integer 4: Enter integer 5: Sum of integers: 15
Circumference of Circle: 1570.8
x1 Percentage of Total 0.166667
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 100 7" | ./foo 
You will be prompted to enter five integers for a pie chart 
Enter integer 1: Enter integer 2: Enter integer 3: Enter integer 4: Enter integer 5: Sum of integers: 15
Circumference of Circle: 1570.8
x1 Percentage of Total 0.01
```

Changing it from `6` to `100` gave a different value -- `0.166667` vs `0.01`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain to me why removing cin >> SumOfIntegers solved my problem? I am a total beginner and this is the first program I am writing.

Comment: The `cin >> SumOfIntegers` _overwrites_ the stored value with whatever number you type in at the keyboard. :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to how the division operator works in C++ (don't ask why, it's dumb but it is what it is) when every number is a whole number it treats it weird. If you implement a .0 on the end of one of your numbers it will work.

ex:

2.0 instead of 2

Don't have visual studio installed on this machine so i can't verify if x1 + 0.0 will work or not, but something to try.

also it's better to be calculating the sum instead of inputting it.

P.S. you don't need to do the casting to double either.  since they're all doubles already, your casting a double to a double and not achieving anything but wasting clock cycles.  Just x1/SumOfIntegers will work.

Comment: Often a good catch, but these variables are all declared `double`, despite frequently being called _integers_.

Comment: ah yes, after looking at the code again i see they're all doubles, not an int/double combo.